# How to add data below existing data on sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I recorded a macro and edited it. It scrapes particular data from webpages (found on links) and display them on separate pages.

I want to use the data (VLOOKUP) but the data is on different pages which makes it hard to get an accurate formula.

Every week I change the second line of the code

```
For x = 1 To 20
```

to

```
For x = 21 to ....
```

for example, because new links/data come out every week.

How do I find the last line to add the next lot of data below that?

```vb
Sub Update()
    For x = 1 To 20
        Worksheets("Links").Select
        Worksheets("Links").Activate
        mystr = Cells(x, 8)
        mystr2 = Cells(x, 15)
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$K$1"))
            .Name = "report2_1"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    
        Range("A1").Select
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr2, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "report6_1"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
for x = 1 to 20
```

do

```
for x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row to Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row-20 step -1
```

which will find the last cell used in Column A and subtract 20 rows from it and iterate backwars

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I ran it with the new code and it created alot of new sheets (named 77 to 57)

Comment: @user2742754 that's another problem :) it starts at the last row, so code adds and renames sheets with this line: `Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x`

Comment: Thanks

So add the following

    for x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row to Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row-20 step -1

and remove 

    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x

Comment: I can see that 
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x - names the sheet what ever x is and creates a new one. So definitely dont want that. However now when you remove that it is trying to write the web scrapping information on the Links tab, so we need to select a new tab

Worksheets("Stats").Select
Worksheets("Stats").Activate